# RestEasyClientBuilder ignoring TLS1.2 protocol in WebSphere 8.5 in Java8 unless SSLContext is set programmatically while building restClient

Tags: rest, ssl, websphere, resteasy

I am using RestEasyClient 3.X for consuming restful services from Provider which supports only TLS1.2. Application is running on WAS8.5.5.11 and java is 1.8. SSL protocol enabled is application server is SSL_TLSv2. But RestEasyClient ignores the protocol enabled in application server and tries to make socket connection via TLSv1. When I build RestEasyBuilder with SSLContext set to SSL_TLSv2 programmatically, service works. Is there a way to consuming the service without configuring the sslcontext programmatically in WAS8.5?

Comment: Apache HttpClient 4.5.x overrides the QOP configured in the server, and defaults it to TLS1.1. I have to switch to jersey 1.x to overcome this issue and there is no fix provided in httpClient.